# Restrict auto postback in rad-numeric textbox

Tags: telerik, rad-controls

How can I restrict the postback after exceeds maximum value in Telerik RadNumeric Textbox...
Here is my code..

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="tbDays" AutoPostBack="true"  MaxValue="50" 
        runat="server" ontextchanged="tbDays_TextChanged">
        <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

On ServerSide:

```
 protected void tbDays_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int itemCount = int.Parse(tbDays.Text);
       ///Doing Some stuff..
    }
```

EDIT: How to restrict the postback when we click upper arrow in the numeric textbox after reaching the maxvalue?? or Is it possible to disable the upper arrow after reaching maxvalue.??

Answer (score 0):

"Use the MaxValue and MinValue properties to specify a range for the numeric text box. If the user tries to enter a value that is greater than the value of the MaxValue property, the numeric text box automatically changes the value to MaxValue. Similarly, if the user tries to enter a value that is less than the value of the MinValue property, the numeric text box automatically changes the value to MinValue." - from Telerik

There shouldn't be a value that exceeds the max value as the box should change anything that exceeds the max value to the max value.

Comment: Franklin I edited my question.I knew the scenario that you explained..My problem is if i click upper arrow in the numeric textbox after reaching maxvalue, postback will occured..How to restrict the postback after reaching the maxvalue or how to disable upper arrow after reaching maxvalue...